# SceneKit transform/rotate object

Tags: xcode, blender, scenekit

I want to create an app using SceneKit with a solid 3D object, whose shape I can change using a given user input. Is it better to do this with predefined animations or to make lots of smaller objects (as nodes) and change their arrangements to mimic a single object changing shape? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by '*change shape*' you have following options:

1. If your object is simple (ex: `SCNBox`, `SCNCone`, `SCNCylinder` and alike) and you can *change its shape* the way you want using its animatable properties (ex: chamfer radius of `SCNBox`), then animations is simpliest way to go.
2. If your object is `SCNNode` with contents loaded from external source and by *change its shape* you mean scale/rotate/translate, you can also use animations.
3. If you can create complex object using graph of simple objects with acceptable performance and you can achieve desired *shape change* with animatable properties then you can also use animations.
4. If your object is complex (for example, based on some mathematical model) and/or performance is main prioprity for you, then the only way to go with SceneKit is constructing custom `SCNGeometries` (by filling `SCNGeometrySource`/`SCGeometryElement`) from your model.

Since question have tag **blender** and title mentions **rotate**, then perhaps (2) is best for you.

Comment: I shall try the fourth option I think, thanks for the help